# Joining three tables - issue with alias and Query not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I think the error description is a bit misleading, as I don't see anything wrong with the way the query is ended.  I am trying to join three tables, and this is not working.  Can someone point to what I'm doing wrong?  This is on Oracle, by the way.

```
SELECT s.PITIMEDATE, ROUND(SYSDATE-s.PITIMEDATE) DIFFDAYS, s.SRC, s.VSA6, a.VSA9, c.COMMENTS, c.Actions, c.MYID 
FROM alarm_standing_MAU AS s 
INNER JOIN alarm_MAU AS a 
    ON a.SRC = s.SRC 
    AND a.VSA9 = 
    (SELECT VSA9 
        FROM a 
        WHERE a.SRC = s.SRC 
        AND ROWNUM=1) 
INNER JOIN Alarm_Standing_Comments AS c 
    ON c.SRC = s.SRC 
AND s.SRC<>'LastCheck' 
GROUP BY s.SRC, s.PITIMEDATE, s.VSA6, a.VSA9, c.Comments, c.Actions, c.MYID 
ORDER BY s.PITIMEDATE ASC
```

---

For more info, I was trying to add a second join to a query, but it was getting a bit unwieldy, so was experimenting with an alias.  Here is the initial query - I would be interested in knowing how to improve readability via an alias.

```
SELECT alarm_standing_MAU.PITIMEDATE, ROUND(SYSDATE-alarm_standing_MAU.PITIMEDATE) DIFFDAYS, alarm_standing_MAU.SRC, alarm_standing_MAU.VSA6, alarm_MAU.VSA9 
FROM alarm_standing_MAU 
INNER JOIN alarm_MAU 
ON alarm_MAU.SRC = alarm_standing_MAU.SRC 
AND alarm_MAU.VSA9 = 
    (SELECT VSA9 
    FROM alarm_MAU 
    WHERE alarm_MAU.SRC = alarm_standing_MAU.SRC 
    AND ROWNUM=1) 
AND alarm_standing_MAU.SRC<>'LastCheck' 
GROUP BY alarm_standing_MAU.SRC, alarm_standing_MAU.PITIMEDATE, alarm_standing_MAU.VSA6, alarm_MAU.VSA9 
ORDER BY alarm_standing_MAU.PITIMEDATE ASC
```

Comment: You have `FROM a` while there is no table `a` in your database. You can't use an alias like that.

Comment: OK = thanks.  I'm a bit of a n00b on this.  Is the problem that the alias (alarm_MAU AS a) does not get cascaded through to the sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, you can't use an alias in the from clause:

```
INNER JOIN alarm_MAU AS a 
    ON a.SRC = s.SRC 
    AND a.VSA9 = 
    (SELECT VSA9 
        FROM a                           <-- Oops.  Might try "FROM alarm_MAU as b" ?
        WHERE a.SRC = s.SRC 
        AND ROWNUM=1)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but that's where I would start.

Comment: The `from` clause can be used to define an alias, but it cannot reference one.

Answer (score 0):

If the sub-query is using the same table as the main query then you could have a1 in the main query and a2 in the sub-query e.g.

```
SELECT s.PITIMEDATE, 
       ROUND(SYSDATE-s.PITIMEDATE) DIFFDAYS, 
       s.SRC, 
       s.VSA6, 
       a1.VSA9 
FROM alarm_standing_MAU s
  INNER JOIN alarm_MAU a1
  ON a1.SRC = s.SRC 
  AND a1.VSA9 = 
    (SELECT a2.VSA9 
     FROM   alarm_MAU a2
     WHERE  a2.SRC = s.SRC 
     AND    ROWNUM=1) 
  AND s.SRC<>'LastCheck' 
GROUP BY s.SRC, 
         s.PITIMEDATE, 
         s.VSA6, 
         a1.VSA9 
ORDER BY s.PITIMEDATE ASC
```